# Método recursivo para invertir una palabra, error StackOverFlow

Tags: java, recursión

```
private static String invertirPalabra(String palabra) {
    String res = "";

    if(palabra.length()==0){
        res = palabra;
    }else{
        res = invertirPalabra(palabra.substring(1)+ palabra.charAt(0));

    }
    return res;
}
```

Al hacer este método de invertir una palabra, me salta el error de StackOverFlow. Supongo que se habrá salido de la cadena o algo, pero no sé exactamente el error.

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>   at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
>   at Ejemplo2.invertirPalabra(Ejemplo2.java:70)
> ```

Comment: Es necesario que sea recursivo? O se puede generar algun metodo que haga la inversion de cualquier forma?

Comment: @IvanBotero Daba igual solo estaba practicando , pero de manera recursiva lo he visto más facil. Aunque se aceptan sugerencias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problema.** Antes de ir a la respuesta, veamos esta llamada que estás haciendo:

```java
invertirPalabra(palabra.substring(1)+ palabra.charAt(0));
```

Si la palabra tuviese 10 caracteres, se estaría llamando recursivamente a la función con un string de largo ........

¿Se ve ya el problema?

¡¡¡Sí, de 10 caracteres también!!!... O sea, las llamadas recursivas para `invertirPalabra("abc")` estarían siendo:

```java
invertirPalabra("bca")
invertirPalabra("cab")
invertirPalabra("abc")
invertirPalabra("bca")
...
```

Claramente jamás se va a cumplir la condición `if(palabra.length()==0){`.

No redujimos ningún caracter en la llamada recursiva. ¿Esa tendría que ser la idea, no?

Bueno, ese es el problema.

---

**Solución.** ¿Y si llamamos recursivamente a la función **solamente con lo que falta invertir**?

```java
res = invertirPalabra(palabra.substring(1)) + palabra.charAt(0);
//                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                Esto no se está pasando como parámetro
//                                Sólo se está devolviendo como resultado de la función
```

Así, para `invertirPalabra("abc")` lograríamos:

```java
invertirPalabra("bc") + "a"
   ^-- invertirPalabra("c") + "b"
          ^-- invertirPalabra("") + "c"
                 ^-- ""
```

**Código:**

```java
private static String invertirPalabra(String palabra) {
    String res = "";

    if(palabra.length() == 0){
        res = palabra;
    }else{
        res = invertirPalabra(palabra.substring(1)) + palabra.charAt(0);
    }
    return res;
}
```

**Demo:**

http://ideone.com/iXj5az

---

**Extra.** Si te interesa acortar un poco más el código:

```java
public static String invertirPalabra(String palabra) {
    if (palabra.length() <= 1) {
        return palabra;
    }
    return invertirPalabra(palabra.substring(1)) + palabra.charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

si de recursividad se trata, entonces debemos plantear bien el caso base y caso recursivo:

mejor lo explico con una imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en codigo seria:

```
public String invertirPalabra(String palabra){
    if (palabra.length() == 1){
        return palabra;
    }
    return invertirPalabra(palabra.substring(1)) + palabra.charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solucion Recursiva :

```
    public static String invertirPalabra(String palabra)
    {
      if (palabra.length() <= 1) 
      {
        return palabra;
      }
      return invertirPalabra(palabra.substring(1)) + palabra.charAt(0);
    }
```

Solucion no recursiva utilizando la Clase StringBuilder :

```
    public static String invertirPalabra(String palabra)
    {
      return new StringBuilder(palabra).reverse().toString();
    }
```